# Using "Remote SSH" in VSCode on a target machine that only allows inbound SSH connections

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Is there a way to use the VSCode Remote SSH extension to interact with a remote host that does not allow outbound internet connections?

Is it possible to download the vscode-server files from another system and copy to host?

I read [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/faq#_#what-are-the-connectivity-requirements-for-vs-code-server) but I can't connect the server to internet.

Comment: Connect to what? Are you trying to install VSCode without an internet connection? Please clarify what you're talking about.

Comment: @ifconfig sorry for my bad English , i want use ssh remote extension of vscode , the client is connect to internet but server is not connect

Comment: VSCode Remote access works based on the premise that both the client and server machines are connected to the internet. Otherwise, they are unable to communicate.

If your client device is on the same network as the server device, then there could be a workaround.

Answer (score 167, accepted):

When you connect to a host it executes a bash script that wgets or curls a tarball and extracts it in a directory in your home directory. Here's an offline workaround.

1. Attempt to connect, let it fail
2. On server, get the commit id

   ```
   $ ls ~/.vscode-server/bin
   553cfb2c2205db5f15f3ee8395bbd5cf066d357d
   ```
3. Download tarball replacing $COMMIT_ID with the the commit number from the previous step

**For Stable Version**

**https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:$COMMIT_ID/server-linux-x64/stable**

**For Insider Version**

**https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:$COMMIT_ID/server-linux-x64/insider**

4. Move tarball to **~/.vscode-server/bin/$COMMIT_ID/vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz**
5. Extract tarball in this directory

   ```
   $ cd ~/.vscode-server/bin/$COMMIT_ID
   $ tar -xvzf vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz --strip-components 1
   ```
6. Connect again

You'll still need to install any extensions manually. There's a download button next to all the extensions in the marketplace. Once you have the .vsix file you can install them through the GUI with the **Install from VSIX** option in the extensions manager.

This is kind of a pain and hopefully they improve this process, but if you have a network-based home directory, you only have to do this once.

Comment: server is armhf not amd64. i change url to server-linux-armhf/stable but show 404

Comment: I don't think they are supporting server on ARM at this point

Comment: The Nightly support  , vscode connect to server but cant download files

Comment: @aviso can you add how you manually install extensions? it's one thing to download the vsix and scp it to the server you need it for but trying to manually install from vsix looks at your local host not the remote. Please provide clarity and I'll upvote.

Comment: @WSLUser You install them from the client GUI. Just put them in a place you can browse to on the client. In VScode, connect to the remote host, then in the extension manager click on the three dots at the top right, and select **Install from VSIX**. There's a delay while it copies and installs the extension, but then you should see it listed in the extension manager.

Comment: I can confirm this method works for remote Docker containers as well. I'm using Windows 10 Hyper-V with Linux Container and was receiving ```Failed to download VS Code Server (https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:$COMMIT_ID/server-linux-x64/stable): HTTP 407 - authenticationrequired)```, presumably because of my corporate proxy.  Note that if you've made multiple installation attempts like I did, you'll have a folder in ```~/.vscode-server/bin/``` with an appended timestamp for each attempt.  Remove all and leave a single folder with just the COMMIT_ID (no timestamp).

Comment: Thank you, it worked, even without unpacking .tar file, just drop it there

Comment: This method its work, but VSCode bring new option: "remote.SSH.allowLocalServerDownload": true

Comment: What should be the URL, if I want to do it for vscode insiders (instead of stable)?
Below vscode-insiders commitid doesn't seem to work "c8d44e24dd250d416475a10efe64e35c9e2c65b3".

Comment: You can replace `commit:<commit>` with `latest` to get the latest release build. Example: `https://update.code.visualstudio.com/latest/server-linux-x64/stable`. Respects indicated quality i.e, `stable`, `insider`. Copied my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671520/how-can-i-install-vscode-server-in-linux-offline#comment113512044_57601121)

Comment: @Fakhamatia It only works if the client has internet access. This method is still useful when both the client and the host do not have internet access.

Comment: For the windows server, use `server-win32-x64` instead of `server-linux-x64`

Comment: One thing that affacts me is to set a larger time out`ConnectionTimeout:45`, default    is 15.

Comment: Note that the `COMMIT_ID` is also listed under `code --version`, rather than running step 1 & 2

Comment: If you want this to work with Remote Containers, you can extract the vscode-server archive locally to a path ending with vscode-server/bin/linux-x64/<COMMIT_ID>, then add a mount point in your .devcontainer file as follow:
`"source=<your_local_path>/vscode-server,target=/vscode/vscode-server,type=bind"`

Comment: [404 not found] https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:6ab598523be7a800d7f3eb4d92d7ab9a66069390/server-linux-x64/insider

Comment: @CSQGB, it looks like you're using a stable commit ID with the insider URL, change insider to stable at the end of the URL

Comment: Still works in December 2023.

Comment: Note that you need to extract the vscode-server to the **Server side**, where your VS Code installed probably is Client side.

Answer (score 6):

open vscode -> about

```
Version: 1.46.1

Commit: cd9ea6488829f560dc949a8b2fb789f3cdc05f5d

Date: 2020-06-17T21:17:14.222Z

Electron: 7.3.1

Chrome: 78.0.3904.130

Node.js: 12.8.1

V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0

OS: Darwin x64 17.7.0
```

$COMMIT_ID = cd9ea6488829f560dc949a8b2fb789f3cdc05f5d

Answer (score 5):

A new feature is being added to support offline install

> However, you can now solve this issue by a new user setting in the Remote - SSH extension. If you enable the setting remote.SSH.allowLocalServerDownload, the extension will install the VS Code Server on the client first and then copy it over to the server via SCP.
>
> Note: This is currently an experimental feature but will be turned on by default in the next release

https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2019/10/03/remote-ssh-tips-and-tricks

Comment: This only solves the usecase of where the client has access but the remote host does not. The answer above is still the correct solution.

Comment: This option has now been replaced with `remote.SSH.allowLocalServerDownload` taking "always", "auto" and "off" as options

Comment: In current Version (1.62.0) this setting was replaced by `remote.SSH.localServerDownload` with values of `off`, `auto` or `always`.

Comment: not working if a client has no internet connection either.

Answer (score 1):

Current Version of VS Code: 1.48.2

I just kill the wget process on the server end, and let the client download the archive and transfer it to the server end. That's quite easy as below.

1. make sure that you set in settings.json

```
"remote.SSH.allowLocalServerDownload": true,
```

2. execute the shell scrpits below.

```sh
# to find the <pid>
ps aux | grep wget | grep vscode-server

# kill the process
kill -9 <pid>

# then wait for the client downloading and transferring

# optional: If you want to know the progress, just 
cd ~/.vscode-server/bin/<commit-id>/
watch -n 1 -d ls -rthl
```

Comment: In current Version (1.62.0) this setting was replaced by `remote.SSH.localServerDownload` with values of `off`, `auto` or `always`.

Answer (score 0):

A a work around I have done the following:

Desktop `~/.ssh/config`

```
...

Host *
  RemoteForward 54321

...
```

Remote: `~/bin/wget` in which `~/bin` is added to `PATH` via .bashrc

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/opt/lib/tsocks/
export TSOCKS_CONF_FILE=$HOME/opt/tsocks/tsocks.conf
$HOME/bin/tsocks /usr/bin/wget $@
```

Remote: `~/opt/tsocks/tsocks.conf`

```
server = 127.0.0.1
server_port = 54321
server_type = 5
```

note `tsocks` binary has been scp-ed to `~/bin/tsocks` and `~/opt/tsocks/` has been created with `libtsocks.so` which is normally stored in `/usr/lib64/libtsocks.so`

This is a work around that allows me to have wget functionality with out messing with anything outside my profile to get it to work (eg: no root required ... even though I have it).

Comment: Does this allow you to install extensions on the remote instance with "Install in SSH"?

Comment: yes, this allows you to install remote extensions as well as the main server

Comment: This works great - if you're the only person using VSCode on the host.