# What does Remote SSH install on the remote machine?

Tags: vscode-remote

I need to be very careful with the remote machine that i'll be interacting with. It's a Red Hat 6, and I don't want to install anything extra or redundant. The remote machine isn't mine and I need to be very careful/delicate with it. What are the things that VSCode remote SSH will install on that machine?

Comment: The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718453/using-remote-ssh-in-vscode-on-a-target-machine-that-only-allows-inbound-ssh-co details the component required

Answer (score 1):

VSCode installs the server side executable in your home directory. Unfortunately, it looks like VSCode requires RedHat 7, so Remote SSH might not even be an option for you.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements

If you are worried about inadvertently causing an issue on the Red Hat 6 server, you could try it out on a VM to make sure there are no issues.