# Successfully installed vs code server on remote host, but it's still trying to install something

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have successfully installed vs code server on the remote host following the steps here [SSH with VSCode without internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718453/ssh-with-vscode-without-internet/56781109#56781109).

Now when I ssh into the remote host, I can connect successfully and start working, but in the install terminal, it's still trying to install something, not sure if it's an extension on the remote host that I wanted to install earlier and later successfully installed with vsix. See the log from remote - ssh below, further down there's also output from the install terminal which shows a small bar moving, seemingly indicating progress of something.

How can I stop it from doing this every time I connect to the host? Thank you!!

```
[11:58:58.011] remote-ssh-nightly@2019.10.9540
[11:58:58.011] win32 x64
[11:58:58.013] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+<hostname>", attempt 1
[11:58:58.013] SSH Resolver called for host: <hostname>
[11:58:58.013] Setting up SSH remote "<hostname>"
[11:58:58.028] Using commit id "<mycommitid>" and quality "stable" for server
[11:58:58.029] Testing ssh with ssh -V
[11:58:58.287] ssh exited with code: 0
[11:58:58.287] Got stderr from ssh: OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
[11:58:58.290] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 61671 <hostname> bash
[11:58:58.292] Install and start server if needed
[11:58:58.295] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[11:58:58.639] > 
[11:58:58.639] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[11:58:59.616] > 6c2c07692b2a: running
> 
[11:58:59.677] > Acquiring lock on /users/<myuserid>/.vscode-server/bin/<mycommitid>/vscode-remote-lock.<mycommitid>
> Found existing installation at /users/<myuserid>/.vscode-server/bin/<mycommitid>...
> 
[11:58:59.718] > Found running server...
> 
> *
> * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
> 
> 
[11:58:59.739] > Checking server status on port 32772 with wget
> 6c2c07692b2a: start
> sshAuthSock====
> agentPort==32772==
> webViewServerPort====
> osReleaseId==centos==
> arch==x86_64==
> webUiAccessToken====
> 6c2c07692b2a: end
> 
[11:58:59.739] Received install output: 
sshAuthSock====
agentPort==32772==
webViewServerPort====
osReleaseId==centos==
arch==x86_64==
webUiAccessToken====

[11:58:59.740] Remote server is listening on port 32772
[11:58:59.740] Parsed server configuration: {"agentPort":32772,"osReleaseId":"centos","arch":"x86_64","webUiAccessToken":"","sshAuthSock":""}
[11:58:59.741] Starting forwarding server. localPort 61674 -> socksPort 61671 -> remotePort 32772
[11:58:59.742] Forwarding server listening on 61674
[11:58:59.742] Waiting for ssh tunnel to be ready
[11:58:59.750] [Forwarding server 61674] Got connection 0
[11:58:59.755] Tunneled remote port 32772 to local port 61674
[11:58:59.756] Resolved "ssh-remote+<hostname>" to "127.0.0.1:61674"
[11:58:59.756] TELEMETRY: {"eventName":"resolver","properties":{"outcome":"success","osReleaseId":"centos","arch":"x86_64","askedPw":"0","askedPassphrase":"0","asked2fa":"0","askedHostKey":"0","remoteInConfigFile":"1","gotUnrecognizedPrompt":"0"},"measures":{"resolveAttempts":1,"retries":1}}
[11:58:59.756] ------




[11:58:59.784] [Forwarding server 61674] Got connection 1
[11:58:59.789] [Forwarding server 61674] Got connection 2
[12:01:59.722] > 
[12:04:59.733] > 
[12:07:59.744] >
```

Below is the output on the install terminal. At the end of this output, there's a small bar moving very slowly like a progress bar.

```
6c2c07692b2a: running
Acquiring lock on /users/<myuserid>/.vscode-server/bin/<commitid>/vscode-remote-lock.<commitid>
Found existing installation at /users/<myuserid>/.vscode-server/bin/<commitid>...
Found running server...

*
* Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
* as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
*

Checking server status on port 32772 with wget
6c2c07692b2a: start
sshAuthSock====
agentPort==32772==
webViewServerPort====
osReleaseId==centos==
arch==x86_64==
webUiAccessToken====
6c2c07692b2a: end
```

Comment: I don't see anything that is *trying to install something* in what you posted. If you're referring to the *Received install output* section, it's reporting on what it got in response to the *wget* request in the section just before that point.

Comment: @KenWhite I've just added the output from the install terminal. It has a bar at the end moving slowly like a progress bar. That's what prompted me to think there's something it's trying to install since it's in the install terminal and has a progress bar.