# VS Code Server Commit ID for a particular version

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-server

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718453/using-remote-ssh-in-vscode-on-a-target-machine-that-only-allows-inbound-ssh-co) and have gotten VS Code to connect to a Remote Linux host from a Windows client. Is there a way to get the commit id for a given VS Code version (e.g. 1.46.0) without trying to get the client to connect to the host?

Answer (score 2):

You can click "Help/About" in the option bar to find the info (including commit ID) of the current VScode.