# Cannote [Remote SSH] into a specific server with the VS Code extension from Microsoft

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

The issue only occurs on a specific server. I can connect to it via the command line but not the [Remote SSH] VS Code extension. I can connect to another server with [Remote SSH] too.

The server in error is on a VPN. The VPN is working fine since I can connect to the server via a command line. Here is the log from [Remote SSH]. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
[14:41:24.863] Log Level: 2
[14:41:24.865] remote-ssh@0.65.1
[14:41:24.865] linux x64
[14:41:24.866] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+192.168.11.134", attempt 1
[14:41:24.866] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true
[14:41:24.867] "remote.SSH.sshPath": undefined
[14:41:24.867] "remote.SSH.sshConfigurationFile": C:\Users\ackht\.ssh\config
[14:41:24.867] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[14:41:24.867] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[14:41:24.867] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": off
[14:41:24.867] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[14:41:24.868] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[14:41:24.868] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[14:41:24.868] SSH Resolver called for host: 192.168.11.134
[14:41:24.868] Setting up SSH remote "192.168.11.134"
[14:41:24.871] Acquiring local install lock: /tmp/vscode-remote-ssh-192.168.11.134-install.lock
[14:41:24.874] Looking for existing server data file at /home/roman/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-192.168.11.134-2b9aebd5354a3629c3aba0a5f5df49f43d6689f8-0.65.1/data.json
[14:41:24.875] Using commit id "2b9aebd5354a3629c3aba0a5f5df49f43d6689f8" and quality "stable" for server
[14:41:24.877] Install and start server if needed
[14:41:24.879] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[14:41:24.886] > OpenSSH_8.3p1 Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020

[14:41:24.888] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\ackht\.ssh\config"
[14:41:24.889] askpass server listening on /run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-9997a13dd450836380092d2541009ee2b2f9d775.sock
[14:41:24.890] Spawning local server with {"ipcHandlePath":"/run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-5c21c09319e6872553f5ecc019a6e2d93e894236.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","46133","-o","ConnectTimeout=15","-F","C:\\Users\\ackht\\.ssh\\config","192.168.11.134"],"dataFilePath":"/home/roman/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-192.168.11.134-2b9aebd5354a3629c3aba0a5f5df49f43d6689f8-0.65.1/data.json"}
[14:41:24.890] Local server env: {"DISPLAY":":0","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/home/roman/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/snap/code/59/usr/share/code/code","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/home/roman/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-9997a13dd450836380092d2541009ee2b2f9d775.sock"}
[14:41:24.895] Spawned 1367810
[14:41:24.958] > local-server> Spawned ssh: 1367818
[14:41:24.959] stderr> OpenSSH_8.3p1 Ubuntu-1ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
[14:41:25.099] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:cFmlmLRFMeaBJPXHYi4XxQ2cKkzOfyTVjlSl1AsI1D4
[14:41:25.310] Got askpass request: {"request":"root@192.168.11.134's password:"}
[14:41:25.311] Showing password prompt
[14:41:25.312] Listening for interwindow password on /run/user/1000/vscode-ssh-askpass-516f64f8f5c60d085877a3b707d06a1a94b6dec5.sock
[14:41:25.312] Writing password prompt to globalState
[14:41:28.604] Got password response
[14:41:28.604] Interactor gave response: *********
[14:41:28.604] Cleaning up other-window auth server
[14:41:28.686] stderr> Authenticated to 192.168.11.134 ([192.168.11.134]:22).
[14:41:28.774] > ready: 7f701f2047a2
[14:41:28.793] > Linux 4.14.32-ultimaker #4 SMP Tue Jul 7 12:18:32 UTC 2020
[14:41:28.794] Platform: linux
[14:41:28.882] > 7f701f2047a2: running
[14:41:29.203] > Acquiring lock on /root/.vscode-server/bin/2b9aebd5354a3629c3aba0a5f5df49f43d6689f8/vscode-remote-lock.root.2b9aebd5354a3629c3aba0a5f5df49f43d6689f8
> Found existing installation at /root/.vscode-server/bin/2b9aebd5354a3629c3aba0a5f5df49f43d6689f8...
> Checking /root/.vscode-server/.2b9aebd5354a3629c3aba0a5f5df49f43d6689f8.log and /root/.vscode-server/.2b9aebd5354a3629c3aba0a5f5df49f43d6689f8.pid for a running server
> Looking for server with pid: 15186
[14:41:29.283] > Starting server with command... /root/.vscode-server/bin/2b9aebd5354a3629c3aba0a5f5df49f43d6689f8/server.sh --start-server --host=127.0.0.1 --enable-remote-auto-shutdown  --port=0  &> "/root/.vscode-server/.2b9aebd5354a3629c3aba0a5f5df49f43d6689f8.log" < /dev/null
> printenv:
[14:41:29.296] >     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     PWD=/root
>     LOGNAME=root
>     HOME=/root
>     VSCODE_AGENT_FOLDER=/root/.vscode-server
>     SSH_CONNECTION=10.8.0.10 58928 192.168.11.134 22
>     USER=root
>     SHLVL=1
>     SSH_CLIENT=10.8.0.10 58928 22
>     PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
>     MAIL=/var/mail/root
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
[14:41:29.349] > Spawned remote server: 16523
[14:41:29.394] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:29.480] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:29.543] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:29.604] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:29.659] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:29.718] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:29.787] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:29.846] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:29.920] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:29.971] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.026] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.081] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.138] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.197] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.257] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.327] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.395] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.441] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.502] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.561] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.621] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.682] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.735] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.794] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.855] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.920] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:30.983] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:31.042] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:31.099] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:31.159] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:31.216] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:31.274] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:31.334] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:31.416] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:31.460] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:31.520] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:31.572] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:31.630] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:31.688] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:31.747] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:31.807] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:31.863] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.070] > Waiting for server log...
> Waiting for server log...
> Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.108] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.166] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.235] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.282] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.355] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.409] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.470] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.549] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.589] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.647] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.728] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.769] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.831] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.896] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:32.954] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.012] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.070] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.127] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.213] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.244] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.312] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.393] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.437] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.496] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.555] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.611] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.668] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.739] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.803] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.863] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.921] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:33.983] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:34.041] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:34.097] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:34.164] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:34.224] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:34.294] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:34.351] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:34.411] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:34.470] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:34.530] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:34.613] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:34.692] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:34.772] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:34.934] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:34.947] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.025] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.102] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.157] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.213] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.270] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.339] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.404] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.470] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.528] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.586] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.647] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.701] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.775] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.832] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.899] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:35.965] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.014] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.073] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.136] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.188] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.256] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.323] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.381] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.456] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.497] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.556] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.613] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.671] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.740] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.799] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.862] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.918] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:36.981] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:37.037] > Waiting for server log...
[14:41:37.084] >  
> *
[14:41:37.090] > * Reminder: You may only use this software with Visual Studio family products,
> * as described in the license (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2077057)
> *
>  
[14:41:37.135] > Server did not start successfully. Full server log at /root/.vscode-server/.2b9aebd5354a3629c3aba0a5f5df49f43d6689f8.log >>>
[14:41:37.137] > /root/.vscode-server/bin/2b9aebd5354a3629c3aba0a5f5df49f43d6689f8/node: error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[14:41:37.138] > <<< End of server log
> 7f701f2047a2: start
> exitCode==32==
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId==debian==
> arch==armv7l==
> tmpDir==/tmp==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> extInstallTime====
> serverStartTime==7775==
> 7f701f2047a2: end
[14:41:37.138] Received install output: 
exitCode==32==
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==debian==
arch==armv7l==
tmpDir==/tmp==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
extInstallTime====
serverStartTime==7775==

[14:41:37.139] Terminating local server
[14:41:37.151] Resolver error: Error: The VS Code Server failed to start
    at Function.ServerInstallError (/home/roman/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:64262)
    at c (/home/roman/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:58739)
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (/home/roman/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:63055)
    at Object.t.tryInstallWithLocalServer (/home/roman/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:388682)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async /home/roman/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:293749
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (/home/roman/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:407055)
    at async /home/roman/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:387177
    at async N (/home/roman/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:383945)
    at async Object.t.resolveWithLocalServer (/home/roman/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:386804)
    at async Object.t.resolve (/home/roman/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:1:297790)
    at async /home/roman/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.65.1/out/extension.js:127:110485
[14:41:37.152] Local server exit: 15
[14:41:37.154] ------
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally, if vscode is unable to curl/wget the vscode-server tarball, it is due to internet issues on the remote. A [common workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718453/using-remote-ssh-in-vscode-on-a-target-machine-that-only-allows-inbound-ssh-co/56781109#56781109) is to download the tarball manually, copy it into the remote `~/.vscode-server/bin/` folder. However, in this case, even that doesn't seem to work for the `id=2b9aebd5354a3629c3aba0a5f5df49f43d6689f8`.