# How to offline install vscode-server for windows remote target

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I've been able to follow similar answers for offline installing vscode-server on remote linux targets but I cannot find out how to do this for windows. On the official page for vscode-remote-ssh https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh, it shows that the system requirements for the remote supports Windows 10 / Server 2016/2019 (1803+) using the official OpenSSH Server. So I know it's possible I just can't seem to find the download link that vscode-remote-dev uses to download the windows version of vscode server.

The download link for linux follows this format `https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:${commit_id}/server-linux-x64/stable` would there be a specific endpoint for server-windows? I've tried a bunch of different combinations but I could not get anything.

I'm also making the assumption that there is a different download link but it seems a very unlikely case that linux and windows share the same link.

Any help would be appreciated. I've enjoyed using this for remote dev on linux and now I've got an opportunity to use it on windows.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `server-linux-x64`, `server-win32-x64` should be used and it will download the correct windows version of the vscode-server.

I did find this in the comments of this question. [Using "Remote SSH" in VSCode on a target machine that only allows inbound SSH connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718453/using-remote-ssh-in-vscode-on-a-target-machine-that-only-allows-inbound-ssh-co/56781109#56781109).