# How to access a 2 hop SSH from a specific server that permits SSH only from within its network, using VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am encountering an issue where I need to SSH into a specific server that allows SSH to a system2 controller only from within its network. Unfortunately, accessing the system2 controller from outside this server is not possible. While I am able to SSH into the specific server using VSCode, I am unable to open a new window to access the folders within the system2 controller. Although I am able to access the required folders via the VSCode terminal, I am unable to do so by opening them in a new window.

What could be the possible solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The following thread works but not in all machines i tested:

[Using-remote-ssh-in-vscode-on-a-target-machine-that-only-allows-inbound-ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56718453/using-remote-ssh-in-vscode-on-a-target-machine-that-only-allows-inbound-ssh-co?rq=2)