# How to prevent VSCode from raising XHR error when it tries to download the vscode-server locally?

Tags: visual-studio-code, xmlhttprequest, vscode-remote

VSCode fails to download the vscode-server on my remote ssh host. With this I am fine. As a fallback VSCode tries to download the vscode-server on my local machine, to then copy it to the remote machine via ssh. This fails du to an XHR error.

The output generated by VSCode looks like this:

```
> Trigger local server download
> 8d402d7e9ae2:trigger_server_download
> artifact==cli-alpine-x64==
> destFolder==/home/rschmidtner/.vscode-server==
> destFolder2==/vscode-cli-af28b32d7e553898b2a91af498b1fb666fdebe0c.tar.gz==
> 8d402d7e9ae2:trigger_server_download_end
> Waiting for client to transfer server archive...
> Waiting for /home/rschmidtner/.vscode-server/vscode-cli-af28b32d7e553898b2a91af498b1fb666fdebe0c.tar.gz.done and vscode-server.tar.gz to exist
>  
[14:17:21.193] Got request to download on client for {"artifact":"cli-alpine-x64","destPath":"/home/rschmidtner/.vscode-server/vscode-cli-af28b32d7e553898b2a91af498b1fb666fdebe0c.tar.gz"}
[14:17:21.193] Downloading VS Code server locally...
[14:17:21.332] Terminating local server
[14:17:21.333] Exec server for ssh-remote+scedge01 failed: Error: XHR failed
[14:17:21.334] Error opening exec server for ssh-remote+scedge01: Error: XHR failed
[14:17:21.336] Local server exit: 15
```

The developer tools output looks like this:

```
ERR XHR failed: CodeExpectedError: XHR failed
    at ee.rb (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2718:21055)
    at async ee.qb (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2718:20332)
    at async ee.Ob (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2719:11484)
    at async ee.jb (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2718:17969)
```

I have the strong assumption that this is proxy related. I connect to the remote host via the proxy. The proxy domain and port are correct, I double checked. I also played arround with proxy settings in VSCode like suggested in [Visual Studio Code "Error while fetching extensions. XHR failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177216/visual-studio-code-error-while-fetching-extensions-xhr-failed), but without success. Installing extensions on my local machine works without raising XHR errors. How can I prevent VSCode from running into XHR errors while downloading the vscode-server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running VSCode version 1.85.0, it seems to be a CDN server configuration issue, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/200512 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/9246.

A fix has been merged to VSCode, I think it will be included in the next release : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/200554.

I understand that downgrading to 1.84 is a workaround. You can also manually install the server to your remote host by following the answer in this theda : [How can I install vs-code-server manually and tell vs-code-remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56073276/how-can-i-install-vs-code-server-manually-and-tell-vs-code-remote)